# Android: Run a thread in the background without delaying activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-lifecycle, android-cursor

I have a process that pulls Contact info, and it takes a long time - 4 seconds.  I do not want it to interfere with the user experience in my app.  I have 2 questions:

1. How can I run this in its own thread so it does not delay the activity from drawing on the screen
2. Is there a way to speed this up? (Am I doing it inefficiently?)

I've tried calling the getContacts() method below from onCreate, from onStart, and onResume, but in all cases the screen does not appear until after method has run completely.

Here's the code:

```
private void getContacts() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d("ManageFriends","getContacts Start");
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
                };
                String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + " NOT LIKE '' AND 1 == " +
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " AND " +
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOT LIKE '%@%'";
                Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, null);
                DBHelper.insertArrayList(db,"Contacts",DBHelper.cursorToArrayList(cur));
                Log.d("ManageFriends","getContacts End");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.run();
}
```

Note: I'm aware of the big reason this process is slow - I'm converting the cursor result to an ArrayList < ArrayList < String>> and then inserting it into a SQLite db.  But if I could get it to work in the background I'd be happy.

Comment: About `Part 1` of your question, it is already on a separate thread, it shouldn't have any influence on the layout being inflated to the screen for your active Activity unless the content displayed is dependent on the information being obtained in your thread.

Comment: To update your screen periodically, you'll need to invoke back to the UI thread from your thread to update your screen.  This will make the app appear more responsive.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` for threading. So much easier. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I do have an autocompleteTextView tied to data that this method pulls, but that shouldn't populate when the activity starts. So, no. And yet I'm getting a 4-second delay

Comment: `like ''` is possibly not very efficient, I would use `= ''` directly

Comment: starting a thread is done using `thread.start()`. `thread.run()` invokes the thread's method directly in the current thread.

Comment: @njzk2 - that made a HUGE difference, and I can see in the log that it's running concurrently with the main load processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `daemon` thread.

`Daemon` threads are typically used to perform services for your application/applet (such as loading the "fiddley bits"). The core difference between user threads and daemon threads is that the JVM will only shut down a program when all user threads have terminated. Daemon threads are terminated by the JVM when there are no longer any user threads running, including the main thread of execution.

**P.S. It is a low priority thread**

Sources:

- [JavaTpoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/daemon-thread)
- [JGuru](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=43724)

**Example**

```
Thread thread = new Thread();

thread.setDaemon(true);

thread.start();
```

**EDIT!**

Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for `AsyncTask` which is a thread for UI background tasks.

Comment: documentation says `This is not normally relevant to applications with a UI.`

Comment: I used the thread.start() which made the difference. I left out the setDaemon, which didn't have an impact in my case.

Comment: @Scott I editted in some useful information for you!

Comment: @njzk2 editted in `AsyncTask` which is specifically for UI threads

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CursorLoader which loads data from ContentProvider in the background thread: [Retrieving a List of Contacts](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)